# avahi unreliable service resolution

Tags: c, linux, mdns, avahi

When running the `avahi-browse <service_name> --resolve` the browser does not find all the nodes every time or does not resolve all of them. My suspicion is that the nodes that are already cached and stored in the daemon memory don't always show up in the browser.

Often a message as below pops up, informing that the resolver timed out. My service is called `wannabe` with a type of `_wannabe._tcp`.

```
(Resolver) Failed to resolve service 'wannabe' of type '_wannabe._tcp' in domain 'local': Timeout reached
```

Is there a way for `avahi-browse` (or in general all the avahi library) to reliably return all the announced services possible, including the once that are already cached? Is there a way to debug it somehow?